# Wamp server not turning to green after changing php version

Tags: php, wamp

I recently upgrade wamp-php from php 5.5.12 to php 5.6.26. I downloaded php 5.6.26 and kept in `bin\php`. To upgrade from old one to new one, I copied `php.ini`, `phpForApache.ini` and `wampserver.conf` files from old versions to new. Then made the path changes in both files. Now there are both versions of php on my wamp.

But when I change the version to php 5.6.26 by click on wamp tray icon, it is not turning green, also not working. It is working with old version fine.

Comment: Is the tray icon red or orange? You can check out the log files in wamp/logs/ l, also the Events in Windows -> Control Panel (Application events).

Comment: tray icon is orange

Comment: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check php.ini in apache\bin folder and also check new php path mentioned in "Environment variables" of "Advanced" tab of "System Properties".

If it's still not work, check Is you apache is working correctly after doing the changes, sometimes apache stopped working because of some configuration failures.
And also verify is your php version you have downloaded is compiled by using the same VC++ version that you are using.?

Comment: Never put the PHP folder on the PATH environment variable when using WAMPServer. It is not necessary and will just cause you problems